# How to add header in IHttpActionResult in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hi i am developing API's using Web API 2. I know how to add header when using `HttpResponseMessage`. Now I am using `IHttpActionResult`.

Below is my sample current code.

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, LoginResponse);
```

How can I add a header when I am returning content?

Whenever I use `HttpResponseMessage` I will be having request object and I can add header.

Below code I tried in `HttpResponseMessage`.

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
return response;
```

In this case where can I add header values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom `IHttpActionResult` which decorates a real one but exposes a way to manipulate the response:

```
public class CustomResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly IHttpActionResult _decorated;
    private readonly Action<HttpResponseMessage> _response;

    public CustomResult(IHttpActionResult decorated, Action<HttpResponseMessage> response)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _response = response;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await _decorated.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

        _response(response);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then use this in your action:

```
return new CustomResult(Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, loginResponse), res => res.Headers.AddCookies(new []{ cookie}));
```

Comment: Thank you peco. It is working a expected. I have not understood what you did in the above code! May i get to know what is explained above? Thank you!

Comment: Here is a short explanation of delegates: https://www.codementor.io/aydinadn/delegates-func-act-in-c-sharp-du107s5mj and here is an example of the decorator pattern: https://assist-software.net/blog/implementation-decorator-pattern-c Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

You can continue to use the `HttpResponseMessage` as you are accustom to and update the header. After which you can use the `IHttpActionResult ResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage)` method to convert to `IHttpActionResult`

Simple example

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController {

    public IHttpActionResult MyExampleAction() {
        var LoginResponse = new object();//Replace with your model
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("name", "value");//Replace with your cookie

        //Create response as usual
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, LoginResponse);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
        //Use ResponseMessage to convert it to IHttpActionResult
        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add header by using this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Some-Header", value);
```

or this

```
response.Headers.Add("Some-Header", value);
```